# Easier way to count users in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this query in SQL Server 2016 to determine how many users have logged into my system.

The `users.lastaccess` column contains a unix timestamp, so I use `DATEDIFF()` to convert it to a `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` date.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS user_logins
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY lastaccess DESC) AS Row
     FROM 
         users
     WHERE 
         lastaccess > DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 02:00:00', (SELECT Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))))
)
```

The result is a simple number, e.g. 75, representing the number of users who have been authenticated on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code returns the `count` of users. It uses `cast` to drop the time-of-day from the value returned by `GetDate` and uses ISO 8601 for the base date/time of the unix system.

```
select Count(*) as User_Logins
  from Users
  where LastAccess > DateDiff( s, '1970-01-01T02:00:00', Cast( GetDate() as Date ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a correlated subquery and a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function at all? And what is that oddball date-based `WHERE` clause? What are you really checking for - the fact that `last_access` is not null/empty??

Just use:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS user_logins
FROM
    dbo.users
WHERE 
    -- your WHERE condition isn't very clear - please add code as needed
    -- but *DO NOT* convert dates to string to compare! Compare proper dates!
    lastaccess IS NOT NULL
```

Also: if you have a non-nullable, narrow, fixed-width column in your `dbo.Users` table, you should have a nonclustered index on this (e.g. on `lastaccess` - is that column nullable?) - that could speed things up quite a bit